# Tensorflow: issues using tf.cond on loss operation

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, control-flow

I am trying to use weighted losses during the training phase but not in the validation phase. My idea was to use `tf.cond` and a placeholder `is_training` which i will feed with a `feed_dict` (True or False)

```
loss = tf.cond(is_training,
               lambda: tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions, scope="loss", weights=loss_weights),
               lambda: tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels, predictions, scope="loss"))
```

It works when I test it on the errors individually but as soon as I use `tf.cond` I get:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: The tensor returned for train_op:0 was not valid.
```

the `loss` operation is used as follows during training (during validation it is simply called by `sess.run()`): 
Regularization losses are added to a `tf.collection`and all losses are added. Then:

```
gradients = optimizer.compute_gradients(total_loss, variables_to_train)
grad_updates = optimizer.apply_gradients(gradients,global_step=global_step)
```

How can should I use the tensorflow control flow?

Edit: `tensorflow-gpu 1.0.1`

Comment: I used `tf.cond`on the weight tensor and this works. However I am still interested why the  approach  above is not working